# How can I view the data in an SQLEXPRESS DB which is connected in Web.config?

Tags: sql-server, visual-web-developer

I'm running Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.  I have added an additional SQLExpress DB to the standard ASPNETDB.mdf.  Both are connected through the web.config.  Everything runs fine.  The connection strings are as follows:

```
<add name="TrempimModel"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|TrempimModel.mdf;
     database=TrempimModel;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;
     User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

But how do I view the data in both DB files?  To my surprise, although the files are refferenced in web.config, the DB Explorer in the IDE does not show them. If I go and add either or both in the DB explorer, strange stuff starts happening - mainly the application is not able to connect to my added DB at application launch.

So what is the best way to view SQL Express table data?  Is it through the IDE, or a seperate application?  And why isn't the DB explorer showing a connection established in web.config?

Thanks,

Gil

Comment: From your description, it seems that your SQLExpress databases are in SINGLE USER mode. If so, follow steps outlined here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlexpress/thread/854cbd26-9971-44b9-8aad-c0fac1ddc5cb steps

Comment: InSane, my databases are created by the membership services script, in the case of the ASPNETDB, and by the Entity Framework CodeFirst CTP mechanism, in the case of my DB.  I have added the connection strings to the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved - surprisingly enough, by eliminating the connection sting altogether.  That way, the database is created by the DB engine and attached automatically by Management Studio, so the data can be viewed over there, while debugging.

I wander why all the walk-through descriptions eliminate this option which is as hassle free as they come...  One point to remember is that you need to exit the Management Studio before running the application with data model changes that will cause the DB to be re-created.